# Execute script in hadoop/hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am new to hadoop/hive. I would like to find one particular column in my hadoop database. I got the query from some another stackoverflow post. But it's looking more sort of unix command, I am not sure where should I execute this.

```
hive -S -e 'show databases'|
while read database
do
   eval "hive -S -e 'show tables in $database'"|
   while read line
   do
if eval "hive -S -e 'describe $database.$line'"| grep -q "<column_name"; then
  output="Required table name: $database.$line"'\n';
else
output=""'\n';
fi
echo -e "$output"
done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a just a bash script.

Run it from a machine where the `hive` command is available

But don't run any code off the internet that you don't know what it does (hint: this reads more than just one column).

If you really want to find a particular column of all database tables, querying your Hive Metastore would be much faster (assuming it's in Mysql, Postgres, SQL server, etc)